# Block su without the '-'

Tags: linux, unix, path, su

I want to block everyone running `su` without the login option.

They can run `su - <user>`, `su -l <user>`, `su --login <user>`. But `su <user>` will be blocked.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Modify the source.

Comment: Due to some reason I was unable to search a compatible source for su. I require it for CentOS 5.5. Got the source for sudo, but not su.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/SRPMS/coreutils-5.97-23.el5_4.2.src.rpm

Comment: Why are you doing this? It seems like you're trying to solve another problem using this, but it might not be the best way to do it.

Comment: @mtak For a specific user I'm using rbash instead of bash and restricting some other commands from `.bash_profile` of the user. But when someone does su <username> instead of "su -", it doesn't use the .bash_profile. So I was thinking, what if I block su without the '-'.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that checks the CLI arguments and passes them to `su`. If the `-`, `-l` or `--login` options are not specified the it will print a warning to the user to use those options.

*** Please note, this would not "block" them from using `su` as they could call the binary directly.

Example `su.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### script to prompt at su
### counter variable
CNT=0
### evaluate all the CLI arguments passed to "su" and check if the login is specified (also let `-V` version argument work)
for arg in $@

do
        if [[ $arg == - || $arg == -l || $arg == --login || $1 == -V ]]; then
### increment counter if login argument is found
                CNT=$((CNT+1))
        fi
done
### check if login argument is given
if [[ $CNT -ge 1 ]]; then
    /usr/bin/su $@
else
    echo -e '*** Please use "-", "-l" or "--login" with the "su" command ***'
    exit 2
fi
```

Make an alias in your user's `.bashrc` file to that script instead like alias `su=/usr/bin/su.sh`. This way, every time you call date that script is run and it lets you know you issued the set date command flag and asks for confirmation.

You may also avoid using an alias, by simply replacing the `su` command, like below, but please also change the `su` binary's name in the script from `/usr/bin/su` to `/usr/bin/su_cmd`

```
mv /usr/bin/su /usr/bin/su_cmd 
mv /usr/bin/su.sh /usr/bin/su
```

Comment: Thanks. I proceeded with the alias method. Though it lacks the direct binary blocking, but this is the easiest affordable way. :D

Comment: Glad to hear! I just now realized you may refer to the fact that you have used "rbash" as stated above, not the the alias I proposed in my answer.

Comment: Like the one you proposed. But not exactly. I did it a month back.